# Docker in docker fails to start if container restarted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

We are running a docker build agent inside a docker container.
It's based off debian jessie, and gets docker directly from docker as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/).

The docker daemon runs fine the first time you start the container, but not the second time. (if you don't delete the container)

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:jessie

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install -q \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        software-properties-common \
        curl \
    && curl -fsSL https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg | apt-key add - \
    && add-apt-repository \
        "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ \
        debian-$(lsb_release -cs) \
        main" \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        docker-engine
CMD []
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  dockerTest:
    container_name: dockerTest
    privileged: true
    image: tomeinc/intel-docker-node:latest
    command: bash -c "service docker start && sleep 2 && docker ps"
```

To reproduce: build the Dockerfile with `docker build -t test .` and then use `docker-compose up` twice. The second time, `docker-ps` will fail with

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Weirdly, if the container keeps running, you can manually start `docker` by running `docker exec -it test /bin/bash` and then executing `service docker start` and `docker ps`.

I'm not really sure how to approach debugging this, any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be that docker thought that it and or containterd was still running(which it wasn't, but the PID files didn't get cleaned up)

Recommended starting approach to debugging issues: Look at the log files. I am shocked by this revelation.

Anyway adding `rm /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.pid /var/run/docker.pid` to the start command before `service docker start` fixes it.